# Unexpected result using pipes in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have got 2 applications 1 generates 6 random numbers between 1-49 (I use LinkedHashSet because numbers can't be repeated):

```
LinkedHashSet hs = new LinkedHashSet();
do{
    int valor =  1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((49 - 1)));
    String num = "" + valor;
    hs.add(num);

}while(hs.size()< 6);

String[] x = (String[]) hs.toArray(new String[hs.size()]);
for(int i = 0; i<6;i++){
    System.out.println(x[i]);
}
```

This one itself is working fine, the problem is in the second one, its suppoused to order the values given by the first application so I use a an ArrayList:

```
System.out.println("Proceso lector");
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList();
while(bf.readLine() != null){
   lista.add(Integer.valueOf(bf.readLine()));
}

Collections.sort(lista);
for(int i=0; i<lista.size();i++){
    System.out.println(lista.get(i));
}
```

I generated both jar and used next command:
**java -jar prog1.jar | java -jar prog2.jar**
The expected result would be the 6 numbers ordered but I only get 3 the whole time though the first program generates 6...

Answer (score 2):

In this loop, you read a line, throw it away, then read another line, which is added to the list:

```
while(bf.readLine() != null){
    lista.add(Integer.valueOf(bf.readLine()));
}
```

This is consistent with seeing 3 lines when you expect 6.

This could be rewritten a number of ways, for example:

```
while (true) {
    String line = bf.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    lista.add(Integer.valueOf(line));
}
```

Note that `bf.readLine()` is only called once per iteration.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt realize that one line was being ignored each time.